# How to allow drops only *between* rows in NSTableView?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, appkit

I have a view-based NSTableView which accepts images dropped in from the finder. I want to be able to insert new images at the specified drop location (left example below) and prevent drops on rows themselves (the right example below).

I have taken a look a delegate methods and NSTableView properties and methods but could not see a way to prevent *drop-on-rows*. Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot showing the drop-between-rows (left) and drop-on-rows (right) behaviour.]

**Figure**: The cursor has not been rendered in the screenshots. In the left example I am dragging in a file called Pic_3.png and NSTableView responds by drawing a line at the location where the new image will be inserted. In the right example, I have continued to drag and positioned it over the existing row in the table view. I doesn't make any sense to insert *on* an existing item so I would like to prevent this behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The delegate method

```
         func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView,
                  validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo,
                    proposedRow row: Int,
proposedDropOperation dropOperation: NSTableView.DropOperation) -> NSDragOperation
```

handles the dragging behavior. The parameter `proposedDropOperation` passes the current `NSTableView.DropOperation`. Return the designated `NSDragOperation` if `operation` is `.above` otherwise `.none`. For example

```
if dropOperation == .above {
   info.animatesToDestination = true
   return .move
} else {
   return .none
}
```

The other `DropOperation` case `.on` represents dragging on the row.

Comment: can we do the same check with outline view?

Comment: Yes, `NSTableView` is a subclass of `NSOutlineView`

Comment: but `proposedDropOperation` is not available in `NSOutlineView`'s `validateDrop` delegate method. is there any other way?

Comment: In `NSOutlineView` it's [`outlineView(_:validateDrop:proposedItem:proposedChildIndex:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineviewdatasource/1533597-outlineview)

Comment: yes here `dropOperation` is not a parameter. so how to determine if its `.on` or `.above`

Comment: Apparently the `.on` operation is not supported in `NSOutlineView` therefore you get the proposed insertion index.

Comment: so there is no way to check if its between or on the row?

Comment: Please read the `Discussion` section in the linked API. Maybe this helps.

Comment: there is a property called `NSOutlineViewDropOnItemIndex` which is actually `-1`. When drop is on a parent node with children proposed index will be `-1` in. Based on this and children count we can decide if its on the row or not.